# Show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(t)$; $t>0$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I did this

Let $I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt} \,dx$

Then, $\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt}\,dx$ (<- why can I do this?) $=-\int_0^\infty \sin(x)e^{-xt}\,dx=-([-\cos(x)e^{-xt}]_0^\infty-t\int_0^\infty \cos(x)e^{-xt}\,dx)=-(1-t\int_0^\infty \cos(x)e^{-xt}\,dx) = -(1-t([-\sin(x)e^{-xt}]_0^\infty +t\int_0^\infty \sin(x)e^{-xt}\,dx))=-1+t^2\int_0^\infty \sin(x)e^{-xt}\,dx\Rightarrow \int_0^\infty \sin(x)e^{-xt}\,dx=-\frac{1}{1-t^2}$

This way, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $I=\int \left(-\frac{1}{1-t^2}\right)\,dt=-\arctan(t)+c$, where $c$ is a constant. So take $c=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Is that correct? And, my doubt is, can I really say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt}\,dx$?

I've tried to use the dominated convergence theorem but I could to prove that I could deal with that derivative in this way, but I couldn't find any integrable $g$ such that $g\geq |f_n|$.

Comment: You have a sign error, your derivative ought to be $-\frac{1}{1+t^2}$, not $-\frac{1}{1-t^2}$.

Comment: What is $f_n$? In any case, in order to use the dominated convergence theorem you may just exploit $$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\leq \min\left(1,\frac{1}{|x|}\right).$$

Comment: Hi, look at 426 page of this book (Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II) http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich2.pdf and example after that (you will find your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the sign problem in my derivative, as commented by Daniel Fischer, I Found a theorem that justifies why I can do that.

"Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f:\Omega\times [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(.,t)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for each $t\in[a,b]$. (here $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$)

Assume that $y(x)=f(x,t_0)$ is integrable for all $x\in\Omega$, for $t_0\in [a,b]$. Assume that $\exists \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\in \Omega\times (a,b)$, and that there's a $g$ integrable such that $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)|\leq g(x)$ for each $t\in (a,b)$. Then

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t):= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int f(x,t)\,d\mu = \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x) d\mu$"

In this case, we just have to take $g(x)=e^{-xt}$, once $|\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\frac{sin(x)}{x}e^{-xt})|=|-sin(x)e^{-xt}|\leq e^{-xt}$

Comment: You can't have $g$ dependent on $t$. To justify differentiation under the integral sign at $t > 0$, choose an $s\in (0,t)$, and take $g(x) = e^{-sx}$. That dominates the differentiated integrand on $[s,+\infty)$, so all is good.